# Подгрузка разных dll в зависимости от разрядности системы

Tags: c#, dll, interop

Мой код

```
public static string Prefix
{
  get
  {
    //Узнаём разрядность системы
    if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
      return "lib_32.dll";
    else
      return "lib_64.dll";
  }
}

[DllImport(Prefix)]
public static extern bool MyFunct();
```

выдает ошибку при компиляции на строке `[DllImport(Prefix)]`:

> Аргумент атрибута должен быть постоянным выражением, типом выражения или выражением создания массива для типа параметра атрибута

Реально ли решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Значения атрибутов не могут вычисляться в рантайме, все значения намертво прибиваются гвоздями в метаданных на стадии компиляции. Соответственно, условия в атрибуты никаким образом добавить невозможно.

У вас два пути:

1. Делать выбор в рантайме.

   ```
   [DllImport("lib_32.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunct")]
   private static extern bool MyFunct32();

   [DllImport("lib_64.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunct")]
   private static extern bool MyFunct64();

   public static bool MyFunct()
   {
       if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
           return MyFunct32();
       else
           return MyFunct64();
   }
   ```
2. Собирать две версии библиотеки с различными директивами:

   ```
   #if LIB_32
       [DllImport("lib_32.dll")]
   #else
       [DllImport("lib_64.dll")]
   #endif
       private static extern bool MyFunct();
   ```

P. S. Наверное, нагляднее делать проверку `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`, а не `IntPtr.Size == 4`.

Comment: 1. Функции в Dll названы одинаково **MyFunct**. 2. Не вариант делить ПО для двух систем (либы системные, не мои). Можно же как-то обойтись и одним дистрибом.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Исправил первую версию.

Comment: Да проблемма не в определении разрядности, а в подгрузки разных длл с одинаковым именем функции взависимости от разрядности. Спасибо за вариант с **Environment**

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Так исправленный первый вариант вас устраивает или нет?

Comment: у Вас функции MyFunct32 и MyFunct64, а в длл'ях они называются одинаково MyFunct. длли не мои перекомпилить я их не могу.

Comment: сори EntryPoint = "MyFunct" не заметил, ща проверю

Comment: А почему не Is64BitProcess?

Comment: @pavel Хм, да, вы правы.

Answer (score 4):

Способ номер три: делаем две под-директории, x86 и x64. Перед первым обращением к внешним функциям вызываем функцию [SetDllDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net):

```
class SomeClass() {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    static SomeClass() {
        var basePath = AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory;
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            return SetDllDirectory(Path.Combine(basePath, "x64"));
        else
            return SetDllDirectory(Path.Combine(basePath, "x86"));
    }

    [DllImport("lib.dll")]
    public static extern bool MyFunct();
}
```