# Собрать универсальное C# приложение

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Недавно сделал для себя открытие - при сборке `.NET`-приложения я могу выбрать разрядность целевой платформы. Полез читать в интернеты, и все, что я понял - так это то, что ничего я не понял.

Сам я `java`-ист. С детства думал, что не важно, для чего собирать, важно, какой разрядности `jvm`. Но тут, видимо, все иначе...

Прошу помочь с такой проблемой:

Нужно собрать приложение, которое использует стороннюю `c++` библиотеку. Для библиотеки доступны `32` и `64`-битные `.dll`-ки. От приложения не требуется сверхпроизводительности, так что и `32`-битная версия меня устроит.

Могу ли я собрать свой проект как `32`-битный с использованием лишь `32`-битной `.dll` и рассчитывать на то, что все это дело будет работать как в `32`-битной, так и в `64`-битной системе? И если нет, то как лучше сделать?

И пара второстепенных вопросов, которые помогут мне понять, что я делаю:

Собранное для `64`-битной системы `.NET` приложение ведь будет невозможно запустить в `32`-битной системе, или же это работает слегка иначе, чем с нативными приложениями?

Верно ли я понимаю, что приложения, собранные для систем разной разрядности, запускаются на разных виртуальных машинах, и, как следствие, на `64`-битной версии `windows` установлены виртуальные машины `CLR` двух разрядностей?

Comment: откуда предположение. что _байткод имеет разрядность_?

Comment: @Grundy кажется, не так выразился. Поправлю вопрос сейчас. Все, что я понял - это то, что при компиляции я могу выбрать target-платформу. Значит ли это, что байткод различный, или же разница в другом - я не знаю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все именно так как и кажется: 32х-разрядная версия будет работать *почти*' где угодно, 64х-разрядная потребует 64х-разрядную систему.

Однако, если у вас есть обе версии чужой библиотеки - то лучше оставить свою сборку не привязанной к разрядности (AnyCPU), а при загрузке библиотеки загружать ту, которая соответствует разрядности текущего процесса.

Подробности - вот тут: [Подгрузка разных dll в зависимости от разрядности системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458542/178779)

---

' 32х-разрядная версия не будет работать на 64х-разрядной системе без поддержки 32х-разрядных приложений, например такое возможно на Windows Server Core (спасибо PetSerAl за уточнение)

Comment: Все вроде бы понятно, вот только... Я собираю проект, смотрю на свойства `Environment.Is64BitProcess` и `Is64BitOperatingSystem`. Первый `false`, второй `true`, хотя сборка была для `AnyCpu`. Как же система (виртуалка(?)) выбирает, какой разрядности процесс запустить? И да, я так и не понял - две ли виртуалки стоят в `64`-битной системе, или же `64`-битная виртуалка умеет запускать оба типа приложений. (Ибо интересно, может ли быть, что в `64`-битной системе нет `32`-битной виртуалки, и програмка просто не запустится). Хех

Comment: @selya спасибо что заметили. Конечно же надо проверять Is64BitProcess.

Comment: Хах, оказывается, полезно иногда давать ответы, ибо можно найти ошибки в старых=)

Comment: @selya что же до второго вашего вопроса - то напоминаю, что в .NET процессы - это обычные исполнимые файлы с точки зрения ОС, а CLR находится в библиотеке `mscoree.dll`. Так что с разрядностью CLR все просто: какая разрядность у программы, такая библиотека `mscoree.dll` и загружается.

Comment: @selya считать же 32х-битную и 64х-битную `mscoree.dll` одной VM или двумя разными - вопрос философский :-) Но, насколько мне известно, на 64х-битных системах по-отдельности они не наблюдаются.

Comment: Хм, ну хорошо. С этим вроде понятно. Но почему мою сборку для `AnyCpu` 64-битная десятка запускает как `32`-битный процесс? У меня с этим непонимания возникли, когда я пытался запустить `wsl` из шарпа. Потом доперло, что процесс `32`-битный, пришлось прописывать путь как `C:\Windows\Sysnative`, чтобы `wsl` запустить...)

Comment: @selya потому что AnyCPU бывают двух типов: с предпочтением 32х бит и с предпочтением 64х. Очевидно, у вас первый тип оказался.

Comment: ААААААА, все, нашел в настройках эту галку. Ну теперь все стало на свои места. Отметил ответ, спасибо.

Comment: *32х-разрядная версия будет работать где угодно* У меня например в 64-х битной предустановчной среде Windows 32-х битные приложения не работают. Да и, насколько мне известно, подсистема WoW не является обязательной при установки Windows Server в режиме Server Core.